# Creating List of Randomly Generated Values in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am generating a random values and I want them into a single list but my code is making 4 lists instead of one. I want all generated values in single list not in multiples list. I am very beginner in NetLogo. Help is highly appreciated. Check my code and output

**CODE:**

```
ask demands
  [
    ;calculateDistanceMatrics
    set severityLevel random 3
    set slist (list severityLevel)
    print(slist)
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[2]
[1]
[0]
[2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the `ask` construct is run for each of your `demand` agents. This means every time you call `set slist (list severitylevel)` you are rewriting the variable `slist` with a new list that has a single entry (produced from `random 3`).

Instead of rewriting the list, you need to add an element to the list. So if you were to initialize the variable `slist` as an empty list like so `set slist []`, you can then add elements one at a time by either putting them at the front (using [fput](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#fput)) or putting them at the end (using [lput](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#lput)). For example, `set slist fput random 3 slist`.